# OGNL selection with map

Tags: java, projection, ognl

This simple program using OGNL returns me a list of null values instead of [A,B,D].  I've tried `#root{#x.get(#this)}` and still returns me a list of nulls.  Why?  Thanks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


import ognl.Ognl;



public class ognlTest {
    static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        m.put("a", "A");
        m.put("b", "B");
        m.put("c", "C");
        m.put("d", "D");

        List<String> k = new ArrayList<>();
        k.add("a");
        k.add("b");
        k.add("d");


        Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        context.put("x", m);

        Object expression = Ognl.parseExpression( "#root.{ #x[#this] }");

        Object value = Ognl.getValue( expression, context, k);

        System.out.println("value = [" + value + "]");

    }
}
```

**Update:**

Use `#root.{#z=#this, #x[#z]}`.  Silly but it works.  I believe this is a bug but Apache OGNL 4 is in limbo and OGNL 3.0.6 is ... I'm not sure it is maintained; the distribution doesn't even compile because it has wrong dependencies.

Comment: Could you tell what you are trying to achieve with that expression? Maybe be it can be done in a different way. Anyway for the explanation why it returns nulls see my answer.

Comment: It should return [A,B,D].  Given an array of keys, give me back a list of values from a map.

Comment: Yes, but why you are doing it like that? Why use projection over root object and not over map? Any reason for that?

Comment: Updated my answer with HOW to select from map with list as keys.

Comment: This `#root.{#z=#this, #x[#z]}` confirms that `#this` is out of scope when used inside `{#x[]}`. Not a bug.

Comment: @Aleksandr M, `{}` is the projection operator; it should change `#this` to something and not refer to `root`. That is why `#root.{#this.length()}` works as expected: it traverses the list and applies `length()` to each element in the list.

Comment: Correct. But think about it, OGNL first will evaluate expression inside `#x[...]` and after that comes projection evaluation. So `#this` inside `[]` cannot refer to *projection #this*.

Comment: @Aleksandr M, I understand what you are saying but `[]` should not start a new context causing `this` to change. I believe this is a bug.

Comment: If you have inner class and refer to `this` in it then you are refering to inner class not parent class.

Comment: @Aleksandr M, in Java you do not want `obj.doSomething(2*this.x)` for `this` to refer to `obj`.  The plain and simple requirement is `[]` should not start a new context.  It is a very silly usage and if you really did mean `this` to refer to `x`, you can easily do so with `#x[#x]`!

Comment: :) but projection isn't like calling a method, it is more like a query. From the docs: *We call this "projection," from the database term for choosing a subset of columns from a table.* And this in `[]` will not refer to `x` but to the root (in this case `k`).

Comment: @Aleksandr M, I'm sorry but this "query" and "method" distinction is not valid. Nothing gets done in Java without a method call. You can continue to think this is a feature and I'll continue to believe it is a bug.

Comment: Of course we can ;). Consider this `query = #x[#this]; obj.projection(query);`. `#this` is a root (obj in this example), isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

First of all it is always better to indicate type of key when getting values from a map. For example by constructing a new String.

```
map[new java.lang.String(#this)]
```

That said, this expression returns nulls because `#this` in this context refers to root object.

You can easily verify this by creating your `k` list before map and putting `k.toString()` as a key.

```
m.put(k.toString(), "k_is_here");

Object expression = Ognl
                   .parseExpression("#root.{ #x[new java.lang.String(#this)] }");
```

The output will be:

```
value = [[k_is_here, k_is_here, k_is_here]]
```

**Update**

For selecting values from map with list values passed as keys use this expression:

```
#x.entrySet().{? #this.key in #root}.{#this.value}
```

First it will select from `entrySet` of map all entries which key is in the list and then gets values of selected entries.

Comment: Why should #this be the root object when #this is supposed reference each element of #root instead?  As I understand it, #this refers to each element of a collection when used with selection operator `.{}`. For example, #root.{ #this.length() } will return [1,1,1] not [3,3,3].

Comment: Also I'm not convinced I need to pass a new String into a map that I already know uses String keys.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue: Have you tried the code I've posted? It is clearly seen that `#this` in this context inside `[]` reference root object.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue: As for the String key, consider map where key is a String and one of the keys is `1`. When you try to get a value from that map and you pass `1` how OGNL suppose to know is it String or integer?

Comment: I did run your code but your explanation does not explain why `#this` doesn't work the way you explain it in more typical contexts such as `#root.{#this.length()}`.  OGNL understands the difference between 1 and "1".  For "1" you pass in `\"1\"`.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue: Yes, but if you pass a variable then OGNL cannot always determine it type. My guess is `#this` inside `#x[#this]` is out of projection scope. So it is global scope and `#this` returns global this which is root object.

Comment: If I pass in an Object of the wrong type, then it is good that I get Exception for it. No need to try to force a cast.  If `#this` is losing scope because of `[` then it is a bug.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue: Not sure it is a bug. Because scope is different. It is like using this in java class. But maybe, maybe. Anyway this answer answers you question and provides way to do what you want, accept/upvote it.